# Python 3 handling error TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, excepciones

Cuando corro este codigo:

```
i=0
while i<5:
    i=i+1;
    try:
        SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
    except client.get_order as e:
        print ("This is an error message!{}".format(i))
#End while
```

Obtengo el siguiente error: TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Lei esta pregunta en stack en ingles [Exception TypeError warning sometimes shown, sometimes not when using throw method of generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163697/exception-typeerror-warning-sometimes-shown-sometimes-not-when-using-throw-meth/18163759#18163759)
 y tambien lei esto: https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/a-very-picky-except-in-python-d9b994bdf7f0

Con este código logro solucionarlo parcialmente, puesto que las iteraciones continúan pero no logro capturar el código de error e imprimirlo

```
i=0
while i<5:
    i=i+1;
    try:
        SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
    except:
        print ("This is an error message!{}".format(i))
#End while
```

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te ocurre porque en la cláusula `except` debes indicar qué excepción capturas. Una excepción es una clase que herede (directa o indirectamente) de la clase base `Exception`.

En cambio tú has puesto `client.get_order` donde python esperaba el nombre de la excepción, y eso que has puesto es un método de un objeto, y no una clase que herede de `Exception`.

Tienes dos soluciones, la mala y la buena.

La **mala** es capturar directamente `Exception`, así:

```
try:
    SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
except Exception as e:
    print ("This is an error message!{}".format(e))
```

El bloque `try` podría generar diferentes excepciones, por diferentes motivos. Ya que cualquiera que sea la excepción generada heredará de `Exception`, tu `except` la capturará. Pero esto significa que tratarás de la misma forma todas las excepciones que pueden ocurrir, lo cual no suele ser lo mejor. Lo correcto sería tener múltiples bloques `except`, uno para cada posible excepción, y manejar cada una como le corresponda.

Entonces, la **buena** es capturar individualmente cada posible excepción:

```
try:
    SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
except Exception1 as e:
    # Codigo para manejar Exception1
except Exception2 as e:
    # Codigo para manejar Exception2
# etc.
```

Si la excepción que se produce no es ninguna de las que habías previsto, se "elevará" hacia la función que haya llamado a la tuya, y si ésta tampoco la trata apropidadamente, se seguirá elevando hasta que quizás "rompa" la ejecución del programa y se muestre al usuario.

Es tentador añadir un bloque final `except Exception as e:` para capturar todo lo que no haya entrado por uno de los bloques anteriores, pero en ese caso estarías *enmascarando* un posible error en tu programa. El error ocurriría de todas formas , y si no es tratado correctamente podría influir en los resultados de otras partes. Vale más dejar romper el programa ante errores no previstos, para después añadirlos en su correspondiente `except` que los maneje.

De hecho en tu caso probablemente no sepas qué excepciones puede elevar tu bloque `try:`. Tendrías que mirar la documentación para averiguarlo y escribir su `except` específico, o bien no poner el `try:`, dejar que el programa rompa, y examinar el error que muestra para averiguar "por las malas" qué excepción produjo.

De nuevo es tentador poner un  `except Exception as e:` para capturarlas todas, sea la que sea, y así no tener que andar averiguando cuál es cada posible excepción, pero no es la mejor solución. Puedes usar provisionalmente ese mecanismo, para que en lugar de romper el programa, te muestre qué excecpión fue (`print(e)`) y después agregarle el `except` específico, pero puede ser peligroso que el programa siga ejecutándose después de haberse producido una excepción no manejada correctamente, por eso es mejor directamente no manejarla, pues eso mostrará también que excepción se produjo y además *detendrá el programa*.

## Actualización

Tras la información adicional suministrada por el usuario en unos comentarios, puedo ser algo más específico en el ejemplo de código.

Al parecer se está usando la biblioteca [`python-binance`](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) la cual declara [un par de excepciones](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html). Si queremos capturar esas específicamente, es necesario que estén declaradas pues no son excepciones estándar que python reconozca de antemano. Basta importar su definición del módulo apropiado:

```
from binance.exceptions import BinanceAPIException, BinanceWithdrawException
```

`BinanceAPIException` es una excepción un poco particular. Indica que al invocar una API (remota, entiendo) se ha producido un error. En lugar de generar una excepción diferente para cada posible error, esta biblioteca ha optado por generar una sola excepción y suministrar al usuario, dentro del campo `code` de la excepción, el código numérico de error retornado por la API. Esto obliga al usuario a mirar la documentación de la API para averiguar el significado de [todos los posibles códigos de error](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/errors.md).

Por tanto el código de tratamiento de excepciones en este caso particular podría quedar así:

```
try:
    SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
except BinanceAPIException as e:
    print("Excepción en la API.", generar_mensaje(e.code)) 
except BinanceWithdrawException as e:
    print("Ha fallado la retirada de fondos")
except Exception as e:
    # Esto último no debería hacerse, capturar una excepción "comodin"
    # y no tratarla puede llevar a errores
    print("Se ha producido otra excepción no prevista")
    print("Razón:", e)
```

Y después puedes crear la función `generar_mensaje(c)` que devuelva una cadena apropiada para el código numérico `c`. Por ejemplo:

```
def generar_mensaje(c):
   codigos = {
     -1002: "No autorizado",
     -1003: "Demasiadas peticiones",
     -1007: "Timeout",
     -1015: "Demasiadas nuevas órdenes",
     -1100: "Caracteres ilegales",
     -2013: "La orden no existe",
   }
   msg = codigos.get(c, "[Mensaje no traducido]")
   return "Código: {}. {}".format(c, msg)
```

Observa el uso de `.get()` para obtener el mensaje con el código dado, proporcionando un valor por defecto si no se encuentra el código en el diccionario.

Comment: El try: lo estoy usando porque genera errores de coneccion y quiero que vuelva a intentar cuando genere el error, pero la intención de imprimir el error es "por si acaso" existe otro error que no sea de conexion.

Comment: Esta es la documentación de la [libreria](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html) en cuanto a excepciones, con tu consejo aplicando la solución "mala" he logrado imprimir los mensajes de error ahora el reto esta en saber cuales son las excepciones,
con except BinanceAPIException as e: obtengo NameError: name 'BinanceAPIException' is not defined. Gracias, Me toca seguir leyendo

Comment: Leyendo los [codigos de error de la API oficial](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/errors.md#-2013-no_such_order) Logre hacer esto:

`try:
    SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
except Exception as e:
    if e.code==-2013:
        print ("Order does not exist");
    #End If`

Asi que dentro del exception colocar un else if para cada codigo de error me parece lo mas apropiado

Comment: @Chuox Entiendo. He ampliado la respuesta para darte ideas de cómo tratar tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
i=0
while i<5:
    i=i+1;
    try:
        SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
    except as e:
        print (f"This is an error message!{e}")
#End while
```