# Excepción catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Tags: python, excepciones

Estoy intentando hacer una función que me sume los elementos de una lista e ignore los elementos no numéricos, ahora mismo lo tengo así pero me salta un error al manejar la excepción de este tipo:

> catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Entiendo que es porque estoy intentando capturarlo sin especificar la excepción pero no se como indicar cual es en ese caso

```
def sum_of_list(values):
    suma = 0
    for val in values:
        try:
            numeric_val = float(val)
        except val as e:
            break
        suma += numeric_val
    return suma
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no `except ValueError as e:`?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Python 3 handling error TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216562/python-3-handling-error-typeerror-catching-classes-that-do-not-inherit-from-bas)

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes cambiar `except val as e:` por `except ValueError as e:`. Además, si tuvieras este arreglo: `values=[2, 56.2, 78, 9, "Pepito", 45, 9.8, "Juanito", 200.23]`, si utilizas `break`, entonces el resultado sería `145.2`, pero si lo sustituyes por `continue`, el resultado es: `400.23`.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Tengo entendido que las excepciones se manejan de esta manera:

```
"except" [expresion ["as" identificador]] ":
```

Por lo que en `except` debes capturar la excepción especifica que estas capturando. Y es justamente el error que esta arrojando

> catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

O sea que estas capturando una clase que no hereda de BaseException, o sea `val`, una clase validad seria `ValueError` o al menos eso creo sacando [información de aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

Otra cosa interesante es lo que menciona @Firefly acerca del break.

Aquí hay algunas preguntas formuladas hace tiempo con respuestas interesantes relacionadas con tu problema.

La segunda respuesta en esta pregunta hace un desglose de lo que acabo de decir, el problema del OP era mas bien en que instanciaba... pero eso no importa.
[Es este link chidorri azul.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351160/typeerror-catching-classes-that-do-not-inherit-from-baseexception-is-not-allowe)

La primera respuesta en esta pregunta va mas relacionada con tu problema a mi manera de ver, podrías echarle una leída
[como complemento a las respuestas de aqui.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216562/python-3-handling-error-typeerror-catching-classes-that-do-not-inherit-from-bas)